# kango how to open popup on click of Context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, kango-framework

I am creating Kango Extension.

under main.js here is my code

```
kango.ui.browserButton.setPopup({url:'popup.html'});
kango.ui.contextMenuItem.addEventListener(kango.ui.contextMenuItem.event.CLICK, function()     {
/here i want to open popup.html

});
```

When i click on Extension icon. my popup script is opening.

Now i want when i click on Context Menu item popup will appear

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to open the popup by code :(

You may refer to issue raise on github for at
https://github.com/KangoExtensions/kango/issues/60